# Dealt 3 cards goes to showdown…

Tags: texas-hold-em, tournament

Tournament game of Texas hold’em.  Hand is dealt, and goes to two players all the way to showdown.  I show my cards A/4 and opponent shows 3 cards 8/6/3 clubs and makes no hand.  They declare a misdeal and give him back his chips even though I had the winning pair of 4s with an A kicker.  My understanding is that SA (significant action) was clear because he either called or bet all the way to showdown and therefore his hand would be dead correct?

Comment: I'm no floor person, but this strikes me as odd. The player who had 3 cards and didn't declare it from the beginning is probably getting a warning from a floor person. I don't know if it should be a misdeal, but I think it's bad form to refund the losing hand when they essentially were running an angle shoot here in my opinion. I'll ask some floor friends what they think and see if I get a decent answer for you.